# Куда вставить скрипт?

Tags: javascript

Привет:) Помогите, пожалуйста.

у меня есть код:

```
<script>
 var drawTitle= function(){
 var canvas=document.getElementById('title')
 var context= canvas.getContext('2d')
 };
 $(function(){
 var canvas = document.getElementById('title');
 if(canvas.getContext){
 drawTitle();
 }
 });
 </script>
```

...

```
<canvas id="title" width=50% height=10%>
 <h1>There is nothing true, nothing false</h1>
</canvas>
```

А куда надо вставить этот код. Прости я читаю книгу, которая рассчитана что читатель уже знает хоть чуть чуть javascript и там не пишут, куда это девать.

```
context.font='italic 40px sans-serif';
context.textBaseline='top';
context.fillText('There is nothing true, nothing false', 60, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var drawTitle= function(){
    var canvas=document.getElementById('title');
    var context= canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.font='italic 40px sans-serif';
    context.textBaseline='top';
    context.fillText('There is nothing true, nothing false', 60, 0);
};
```

Вам нужно понимать, что мы объявляем переменную context и начинаем работать с её методами и свойствами.

Answer (score 2):

Это у вас HTML-разметка. Ее нужно вставлять не в JavaScript - код, а в структуру HTML - документа, уже после закрывающего тэга  `</script>`
то есть у вас должно быть что-то вроде этого:

```
<html>
    <head>
       <script>
        //тут ваши скрипты
       </script>
    </head>
   <body>
       вот куда-нибудь сюда можете вставлять ваши тэги canvas
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: черт, не могу все это безобразие отформатировать((

Comment: @DreamChild ничего страшного, поможем :)